# TypeScript- Custom Object ID instead of Default MongoDB Object ID

Tags: json, mongodb, typescript, backend

I am getting default MongoDB Object ID from MongoDB by using Typescript. How can I get Custom ID instead of default MongoDB Object ID ?

> {
>       "_id": "**5bbe053ab10bdf08964443d5**",
>       "title": " Moto Z",
>        "manufacture_details": {
>           "brand": "Motorola",
>           "model_number": "XT1650"
>       }  }

This is my Model.ts

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

export const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
    },
    manufacture_details: {
        brand: String,
        model_number: String,
      },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Updated the Model.ts with a new field _id which will be overwriting the default Object ID

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

export const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
    },
    manufacture_details: {
        brand: String,
        model_number: String,
      },
});
```

Now i am able to get Custom Object ID

> { "_id": "M01", "title": " Moto Z", "manufacture_details": { "brand":
>   "Motorola", "model_number": "XT1650" } }